# ¿Cómo cargar una página dentro de un OBJECT después de hacerle un POST?

Tags: html, c#, jquery, asp.net, mvc

Necesito hacer un POST hacia una URL para enviarle algunos datos para validar, así el servidor me puede devolver un nuevo formulario al que le ingreso información adicional.

Originalmente el llamado a la URL se hacía por un GET en una etiqueta `<object>` y en el atributo **data** le pasaba esa URL y un *querystring* Ahora requiero que esos datos por *querystring* sean pasados por POST

El formulario al que invoco mediante ese POST está hecho en ASPX, mientras que mi webApp invocadora está con ASP.NET+MVC+jQuery.

Lo he intentado así y solo me muestra el objeto **FormularioModal**, el otro permanece vacío:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <object id="FormularioModal" type="text/html" data="http://localhost:55666/?parametro1=EJEMPLO" style="width:100%; height:350px; overflow:hidden;"></object>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <object id="FormularioModalPOST" type="text/html" data="" style="width:100%; height:350px; overflow:hidden;"></object>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post("http://localhost:55666/", { 'ParamPOST': 'Por post' })
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#FormularioModalPOST").attr("data", data);
            });
    });
</script>
```

Lo he intentado así también, y el nuevo objeto no se muestra, de hecho en su *data* está el contenido de la página:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <object id="FormularioModal" type="text/html" data="http://localhost:55666/?parametro1=EJEMPLO" style="width:100%; height:350px; overflow:hidden;"></object>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="div2">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post("http://localhost:55666/", { 'ParamPOST': 'Por post' })
            .done(function (data) {
                var obj = $('<object id="FormularioModalPOST"></object>');
                obj.attr("data", data);
                $("#div2").append(obj);
            });
    });
</script>
```

De esta forma me muestra el contenido del formulario pero ya no queda enlazado a su *host*, sino queda como parte de mi página, y necesito que mantenga su conexión a su origen:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <object id="FormularioModal" type="text/html" data="http://localhost:55666/?parametro1=EJEMPLO" style="width:100%; height:350px; overflow:hidden;"></object>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="div2">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post("http://localhost:55666/", { 'ParamPOST': 'Por post' })
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#div2").append(data);
            });
    });
</script>
```

Mi **localhost:55666** solo contiene un par de botones que se muestran dependiendo si la página fue invocada por *GET* o *POST*, solo para emular el comportamiento de la URL a la que requiero conectarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una aproximación, en ella coloqué un formulario que tiene un campo oculto al que se asigna el valor que deseo enviar por POST y luego ejecuto un submit para que me devuelva el formulario de la URL y mantenga su funcionalidad. (Si álguien encuentra algo mejor, agradeceré los comentarios).

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <object id="FormularioModal" type="text/html" data="http://localhost:55666/?parametro1=EJEMPLO" style="width:100%; height:350px; overflow:hidden;"></object>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="div2">
        <form id="frm1" name="frm1" action="http://localhost:55666/" method="post" target="ifrm1">
            <input type="hidden" id="parametroPOST1" name="parametroPOST1" value="" />
        </form>
        <iframe style="width:100%; height:100%" id="ifrm1" name="ifrm1" src=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#parametroPOST1").val("Desde POST");
        $("#frm1").submit();
    });
</script>
```